# Expand bash variable within quotes

Tags: bash

How can I expand `APP_VERSION` so that it gets used in the rest of my script? As it is right now, it doesn't expand and show the argument I pass in via the CLI.

```
APP_VERSION=$2

BOOTSTRAP_RUN='[{"Path":"s3://abc/scripts/emr/deploy_zip.sh ${APP_VERSION}","Name":"Custom action"}]'
```

Comment: The kind of quotes matter -- *single quotes* prevent expansion.

Comment: That said, you shouldn't use simple string substitution when generating JSON.

Comment: `jq` will ensure that contents are correctly quoted and escaped: `bootstrap_run=$(jq -nc --arg path "s3://abc/scripts/emr/deploy_zip.sh $2" '[{"Path": $path, "Name": "Custom action"}]')`

Comment: (note the use of lower-case variables; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph -- convention is for all-caps names to be used for environment and shell variables with meaning to POSIX-specified utilities, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use).